# What would the moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder a distance to the axis of rotation be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

So I understand that the inertia of a hollow cylinder about a tangent axis to its surface is $\frac{M}{2}(R_1^2 + 3R_2^2)$, but what if this axis is not a tangent to the cylinder? So it is some distance form the cylinder.

[image]

Comment: Use the Parallel Axis Theorem

Comment: Hey many thanks for your guidance! Therefore, would it be the moment of inertia about the axis passing through the center of mass, plus MR2^2 where R2 is the distance of the axis passing through the center of mass and the axis a distance x from the surface of the cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the parallel axis theorem you have

$$\begin{array}{r|l}
\text{mass of cylinder} & m \\
\text{radius of cylinder} & R \\
\text{MMOI about center axis} & I_{\rm center} = \frac{m}{2} R^2 \\
\text{rotation axis to center distance} & (x+R)\\
\text{MMOI about rotation axis} & I_{\rm rotation} = \frac{m}{2} R^2 + m (x+R)^2 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you so so much!! I greatly appreciate it!! :D